# Using Django to make a stateful connection

Tags: django

I'm trying to use Django in the following way.

I have a command line utility that runs on the backend, lets call it `foo`.

I want `foo` to run when at least one person is on a django page `foo.com/kungfoo`.

I also need to kill the script, when they leave the web page. Which is possible through Javascript.

However, how do I determine if multiple people are viewing the page at the same time. Ideally, I don't want `foo` to be killed if another person is on the page.

---

The only way I can think of to do this is to have Javascript push an `I'm still here` status to Django every minute or so. Then run a Python script through celery every minute, and check if Django has got an `I'm still here`. If `foo` is running, then kill `foo`.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

I know this question is broad, so I'll make it a little more specific. Is there a way for Django to count the number of people viewing a web page and run a script if that number is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with a [ReconnectingWebSocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket), that way you know when the user leaves the page, or - more helpful in your case - when no users are on the page.

Comment: yeah, I suspected that was how to do it. Trying to avoid the glut of  processing that comes with channels though. Though I suppose Celery beat and Django combined also run quite a high process toll